# spark scala -Array[(String, Array[String])]-storing it as atextFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Please tell me the command for storing `Array[(String, Array[String])]` as a textFile. I have tried

```
val_name.map(x => x._1 + x._2.mkString(",")).repartition(1).write.text("path to store")
```

but i think it works with dataset and not with arrays

Comment: what do you mean by,  it works with dataset and not with arrays?

Comment: How can you use `repartition` on `Arrays`? It will works with `dataset` only.

Comment: Hello @pooja I think it would be helpful to post some input data and how your output should look like